# How can I prevent a user from modifying a source file in the developer console?

Tags: browser

Referring to the picture below, is there a way to prevent users from being able to modify and save local versions of the listed files? The way it is now, users can just modify and save index.js locally to cheat their score (which is bad).

[image: development console, sources tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never provide sensitive data or methods in client scripts, there is nothing you can do to stop clients from editing their scripts.

If you want scores to be secure, run the mechanics of the game server-side. The second-best thing to do is run the mechanics in a flash player. In my experience, people don't find it worthwhile to decompile a flash client simply to cheat their score in.

Comment: I guess I'll re-write all JavaScript to PHP and store the important variables in sessions then. Thanks for the info.